# Read a csv in a pandas dataframe with subcolumns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

My CSV data look like this:

[image]
and I would like to open it in a pandas DataFrame using `read_csv` but I need to get `id` as my first rank column, and `indicator` as subcolumns of the `id` column while the valuedate column in the csv is the index of my dataframe, which would then looks like this:

```
             Value
ID               1                        2
INDICATOR        1     2     3     4      1     2     3
Date
2015-01-02    11.0  12.0    NaN   NaN    14.0  15.0  16.0
2015-01-03    17.0  18.0    NaN   21.0   20.0  21.0   NaN
```